# What to choose between memory and calldata for parameter of type bytes?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721, solidity-0.8.x, smart-contract

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in external function, but none was given.
  --> contracts/NFTERC721.sol:51:77:
   |
51 |     function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;
   |       

                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Solidity version is 0.8.13 and this is ERC721 interface .
Reference : https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna save some gas and you know that the parameter won't get altered along the way, you can use calldata. Otherwise, go for memory.